# SharePoint vs Serverfault, should my question be moved?

Tags: support, stackexchange

After having posted this question and awarded a Bounty on it to no avail i notice there is a dedicated "SharePoint" stack exchange.

[Sharepoint Online auto acceleration not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/786987/sharepoint-online-auto-acceleration-not-working)

Is the SharePoint stack exchange for SharePoint user questions only or also production (serverfault) and development (StackOverflow) type of questions on SharePoint? Does my question have a better chance of finding and answer there and if so could it be moved or should i delete it and repost it there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question has to do with system administration, and is on topic here.

I can't say whether you're more likely to get a good answer at Sharepoint, but most of the questions I have seen there are about using it, rather than administering it.

You might also want to ask about the question on their site meta.